# Which one is correct

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

"How many days has it been since I purchased the subscription" or "How many days have it been since I purchased the subscription".

My limited knowledge says me "has it been" is correct but Google translator translated this into "have it been".
Kindly clarify this to me.

Comment: Why you  think "has it been" correct??

Comment: Dummy subject 'it'is singular

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer to your example question is "It **has** been xx days ...."

From the answer, we see that **has** is the right one.

> How many days **has** it been since I purchased the subscription?

Although the subject is **days**, which is plural, we need **has**, to agree with the dummy subject **It/it**.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How+many+have+it+been%2CHow+many+has+it+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that "How many have it been" is not used.

Comment: Of what verb is *days* the subject? Certainly not “to have.”